# How do academic minors work?

Tags: undergraduate, minor

How much in practice would someone minoring in a subject end up knowing about the subject as opposed to somebody majoring in it?  How much extra work does it take to get a minor?

Comment: You always have so many "?" in your question. I always try to use at most 2 in any question.

Comment: @Pikachu피카츄 Are you suggesting writing longer sentences or creating more threads?

Comment: I tend to structure a question this way (paragraph1) ... (paragraphn) summarizing my situation or what I know + ending with 1-2 questions. So it does not look like there are so many questions

Comment: Vote to close as "Need more focus"

Comment: Just split your blob of questions in separate questions. Then try to answer each one of these separate questions. Then come back to SE:Academia asking for answers. And then get the first and last of the questions presented here closed because they are based on personal opinions.

Comment: Please define useful: +5% in the starting salary? some additional technical knowledge? some insights in another topic?

Comment: @EarlGrey Useful as in any of the following: improves you chances of finding a job; makes it easier to perform your job; increases you salary; helps career growth.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to ask every question as a separate thread but if you insist here you go: I have moved the usefulness aspect of my question to a different question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you not find the answers in the program booklet? It should spell out exactly what is needed to get a minor, as well as exactly what is needed to get a major; comparing the two then answers the question.

Comment: I am asking in general, not for a specific program

Comment: On one hand, I'm sorry to see the downvotes, these are straightforward questions that our site benefits from having.  On the other hand, I agree that you should really show more research effort. Even this site already has some posts about (for example) college minors; showing that you've read those and didn't understand something would probably help your questions be better received here.

Answer (score 2):

> How much in practice would someone minoring in a subject end up knowing about the subject as opposed to somebody majoring in it?

Things vary of course. But a minor is maybe 5 classes whereas a major is 10+. So, about half as much. This can be useful if you only care about certain parts of a subject -- get a chemistry minor by taking physical chemistry + inorganic; you can skip organic and biochem.

It's also sometimes true that if you major in science and minor in certain humanities subjects (or vice versa), you can cover almost all of your gen eds this way. So some people can get a minor "for free" by choosing classes strategically.

As for how useful this is in practice: probably not much. It's a good way to document an interest; i.e., anyone can say "I'm interested in writing," but having a minor in writing shows that you mean it. And of course if your minor means you take more classes than you would have taken otherwise, then you'll know more stuff, and that is usually good at some level. But I suspect that few hiring or admissions decisions would have gone the other way but for the presence/absence of a minor.

Comment: My understanding is that a minor could be very useful to augment your major. Such as a programming or an economics minor to augment ... I was actually trying to figure out how it might work and I was thinking of chemistry as an example: if you wanted to take physical chemistry I assume you would need to have taken thermodynamics and differential equations. And for differential equations you would need calculus I and II, so unless you need  take those classes for your major would your minor turn into a giant undertaking? Or is that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Also, is a "minor" any different from simply doing things you like in a particular field i.e. where does it actually say that you have a minor? AFAIK the diploma doesn't mention your minor nor does you transcript specifically spell out that you minored in something?

Comment: The transcript may say it. You can also put it on your resume / CV. As for physical chemistry: my memory is that it required only univariate calculus. Thermo and separation of variables were covered in the course, and the multivariate stuff was simplified or skipped. But many chemistry majors are not mathematically inclined, so even this level of rigor caused considerable angst. Students probably wouldn't do a minor that involves physical chemistry unless they already had the math background; as you say, a fresh-off-the-boat literature major would need many prereqs to succeed.

Comment: So would the transcript outright say it? Because in the other case, I can't see how you can prove it.

Comment: Often yes. The process for proving a minor is the same as for a major, a certificate, or any other formally-issued credential. And saying you have a minor when the university didn't actually issue one is fraud.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two reasons to minor. One is to get some background in a field complementary to the major: say, chemistry for a biology major. Math and philosophy might actually go well together.

The second reason is just because you have an outside interest in something: literature for a biology major.

Some people get a minor because the required courses at a liberal arts college already contain most of it any way, so, why not. My philosophy minor was like that.

Some people take more than one minor. Actually double majoring is also possible many places.

The requirements for a minor might be approximately half of what they are for a major and might include a few upper level courses.

Some people just want a broad education. This has been true since the Renaissance, I'd guess.

---

Background on the US undergrad system.

A bachelors in the US is almost always four years, doable by a few in less and a few other students requiring more if they have difficulties.

Things are measured in "credit hours" and a credit is (most, not all places) about 15 hours of instruction, or an hour a week for fifteen weeks. Courses vary in how much they count, with three credits being typical but with variations in every program. Labs might require two hours per credit. Some courses are just one credit. There is no standard, but the above is common.

Students take about 15-16 credits per term for 8 terms (semesters), so the requirements for a degree are around 8*15 = 120 or so credits, maybe a bit more.

A major is usually a bit less than 60 credits and the rest of the courses/credits are general education requirements: history and such in a chem major.

So, it doesn't take "four years" for the major, but four years for the degree. But the prerequisite structure of the courses implies that the major courses are spread out with two or three taken per term.

A minor, on the other hand might be 30 or so credits, but the prerequisite structure spreads them out, but perhaps ten courses of 3 credits each taken over 8 terms, or 4 years. Some of the courses in a minor, indeed some in a major, might be required for a bachelor's in any case. So, science is required for many (most?) degree programs and so a chem major can do those in chemistry and get some of their "major courses" by taking the entry level science in chemistry.

Squeezing in two minors in addition to a major is a bit hard, as are double majors. It probably requires overloads and hard work. I once successfully completed 21 credits in a term where 15 was the norm. But I tried 20 in the following term and had to drop one as it was too intense and wound up with 17 that term.

Note that in both the major and in the gen ed requirements there is room for some choice of courses. They aren't rigidly prescribed. Some requirements are just to come up to the total successful credit hour requirement. So, using these options you can take courses in your minor or your major or (for some) whatever you like. There is a lot of flexibility. So, two student math majors might overlap in only the core required math courses and the core required gen ed courses, normally taken early on.

---

A few places like Dartmouth are on a quarter system with four quarters spread over the entire year. Most students there study for three of the four terms/quarters. The individual terms look different but the totals come out to be pretty equivalent. It is just in how you slice the apple. Since the summer quarter is just like the others, it makes better use of campus facilities overall. Faculty likewise normally teach in only some of the quarters, but when I was a visitor there (long ago) the standard was four courses per year.

Comment: "The requirements for a minor might be approximately half of what they are for a major and might include a few upper level courses." How much is that in practice? Does it include the gen-eds? Surely it doesn't take an extra 2 years to complete, right? How much more coursework would someone with a minor take compared to someone without one?

Comment: I like that from this answer it is clear that minor >> negligible :)

Comment: @EarlGrey, I personally value my philosophy minor quite highly. It was a good complement to math.