# What do "minor" and "major" mean (in relation to degrees)?

Tags: university, degree, major, minor

I hear "major" and "minor" when discussing college/university degrees, e.g. having a major in X and a minor in Y. What does it mean to have a "major" or "minor" in something?

At my university (in a Nordic country), we say you have a master's degree/bachelor's degree. Is this the same (i.e., "minor"=bachelor's degree, "major"=master's degree)? Also, what's up with e.g. "having a major in physics and a minor in computer science"? Does this mean you got a bachelor's degree in computer science and then went and got a physics master's degree? Or does it mean that you take some subjects in computer science that are not part of your master's degree?

Is it more common in the US to take multiple degrees? Is this why people say "I have a major in X with a minor in Y"? I heard that because university is expensive in the US, you try to get more "value" out of your enrollment by taking multiple degrees. Is this true? Where I am from it is not common to hold multiple degrees in different fields. Usually, you just have one bachelor's in your field and one master's, or alternatively, a master's without a bachelor's degree.

Comment: Related (though strangely, closed and heavily downvoted): [How do academic minors work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191812/)

Comment: You don't mention a specific country (except that it's Nordic) but it seems that the concept of a minor also exists in Denmark, for example https://studieordninger.cbs.dk/2022/minor/1018

Comment: As @Ivo notes, the concept (or at least a _very_ close equivalent) exists in the Nordic countries too, the OP might just not be familiar with the English terms. For example, I believe Sweden (and Finland) traditionally use *huvudområde* / *huvudämne* (*pääaine*) and *biområde* / *biämne* (*sivuaine*) for "major" and "minor" studies, although some variation exists. See for example [this page from Uppsala University](https://www.uu.se/en/students/degrees/main-and-minor-fields-of-study) (also available [in Swedish](https://www.uu.se/student/examen/huvudomraden-och-biomraden)).

Comment: @cag51 just upvoted that Q&A you linked. Wow, how uninviting this group can be huh. Seems like there's a bandwagon effect with downvotes?

Comment: @Lamar: normally there is a historical reason for such a bandwagon effect (e.g., OP starts insulting people in the comments, the downvotes start rolling, then the mods clean up the comments but the negative score remains). I don't recall what, if anything, led to that question getting such a poor reception though.

Comment: Ok, I can see how that could happen. I'm guessing if there was a solution it would have been implemented already, but I'm guessing it may have its own side effects..

Comment: Since this question asks about majors and minors, might want to toss in "_concentrations_", to cover the set of related things.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen To be more spesific: I study in Norway. The closest thing I can think of is that it is a requirement to take 1 subject outside of your field of study. However, this often end up being something like "how to be a good leader" or something.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think a lot of Nordic students are unfamiliar with this because they are studying through a programme, with all courses planned for them to automatically fulfill the requirements of a major. It's typically still possible to take freestanding courses and stitch together your own major, but that is less popular, especially if you have a clear goal and a suitable programme for that exists. So in the US basically everyone has to think about choosing a major and fulfilling it's requirements, but in Sweden many will finish their degree without ever having heard about _huvudområde_.

Comment: @Vebjorn I don't know how it works specifically in Norway, but if you are studying through a programme, maybe you are looking through the lens of what is offered and required through that programme, rather than the full Norwegian university system?

Comment: Dansk: "sidefag sb. (1993) (universitetsfag som læses ved siden af hovedfag, indført i forbindelse med studiereform, erstatter bifag) bifag"

Specialet skrives i hovedfaget.

Comment: did you know? "majors" and "minors" were originally named that way because one usually finds, in a degree whose "minor" is some subject X, that the quality of learning X in the middle third of the degree often falls significantly flat. [/music joke]

Comment: @Ivo: That is due to the ongoing Anglification. "minor" is [not a Danish word](https://ordnet.dk/ddo/ordbog?query=minor). They don't even *try* to translate or find a better word. There is a perfectly fine existing word, as [soegaard
 mentioned](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/206088/what-do-minor-and-major-mean-in-relation-to-degrees#comment556525_206088). The previous name of that institution wasn't smart enough, so they had to change it to an English one.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In the US, your "major" is the thing you have your bachelor's degree in. "I have a BS in Biology" means the same as "I majored in Biology." Everyone "majors in" something. It is often possible to "double major" by completing all the course requirements for more than one major degree, though few students do this.

Usually there are two requirements for graduation: completing a set of courses required for your major (sometimes specific courses, sometimes "choose one from this list"), and completing at least a set number of credits (typically expected to be completed over 4 years in the US, but some students may take more than 4 years and others may complete far more credits than the number required). The set of courses for a given major is less than the set number of credits, which is how Americans take so many credits unrelated to their major.

A "minor" is a lesser add-on qualification. It usually involves taking 4-5 classes (roughly 1 semester of work; possibly more if other courses are necessary as prerequisites) in an area but the qualifications are entirely up to a given institution. The courses for a minor aren't any more advanced than for a major (unlike a typical masters program), instead it's a minor area of study alongside the main degree. So someone who majors in Biology with a minor in Music took all the classes necessary to graduate with a bachelor's degree in Biology, and also took some additional classes in Music, enough of them to qualify for a "minor". Someone with a major in physics and a minor in CS took all the courses they needed to earn a bachelor's degree in physics while also taking a few undergraduate CS classes.

In the US, undergraduate education is quite broad and involves taking a lot of elective courses outside of the major. Personally I got two minors without really needing to take any "extra" classes, I just chose enough of my elective credits in specific areas to qualify. So, while minors are completely optional, a lot of people end up collecting them because it's not that much additional work.

I would say also that a minor doesn't count for a whole lot. It's not really a separate degree, it's just an added notation to the main degree. The courses you take might be useful themselves, but it's not usually a qualification people are looking for directly when hiring or something.

Comment: There are cases in the US where a major isn't required for a bachelor's. My undergrad offered a Bachelor's of General Studies which required a broader-than-normal set of courses across fields in lieu of the intensive set of classes within a major. I know people who used a BGS to take coure courses in many different languages but without fulfilling major requirements for any of them.

Comment: @CompEcon Ah yes, the danger of ever saying "everyone"/always/never/etc. :) Colloquially, though, even in that case it's common to say "I'm majoring in General Studies" or something like that, even if the school officially calls it "no major".

Comment: This is perhaps extraneous (since OP didn't ask), but at least at my alma mater, you could *double major* - if the degrees matched; i.e. filling the requirements for two BAs or two BSes. If they were different, you had to get a *double degree* which was difficult to do in a typical 12-quarter undergrad enrollment.

Comment: As an additional example, I majored in Computer Science, and just needed one additional class from the Math program to gain a minor.  Additionally, I regularly took high level English classes as an elective (to take a break from computers/science/math) and ended up picking up enough credits for a minor there as well.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - I loved those upper division English classes. One evening a week to just sit in a comfy chair and read a novel or a Shakespeare play instead of cranking through a problem set…

Comment: When I went to MIT, the humanities portion of the graduation requirements required you to have a "concentration" of N classes in a particular humanities area (e.g. music, literature, languages). But it looks like this is gone.

Comment: At my institution in my year, there were several people who _triple-majored_ in Electrical Engineering, Computer Science, and Mathematical Sciences (i.e. applied mathematics) because if you selected your in-major courses carefully, you could triple-major with only an additional semester's worth of courses. My institution did not have the concept of "minor" at that time.

Comment: Some university programs *require* a minor in addition to a major to graduate.

Comment: Does this mean students just enroll in something like a "general Bachelors degree" at first and later choose their major? And is it possible to achieve a degree without choosing a major at all? If not, there surely needs to be a point in time where you have to decide latest.

Comment: @kopaka Depends on university policy; some may make you declare a major from the start but allow you to change, others may let you go undeclared, some with a deadline and others without. But universities also want people to graduate in time, so they'll at least encourage taking any early prerequisite courses right away. E.g., for most biology degrees if you aren't taking general chemistry your first year you will never finish in 4 years because it's a prereq for courses that are prereqs for courses that are prereqs for courses.

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading. If I double major in Bio and Chem, I can graduate with just a degree in Biology. Double degree's usually require additional requirements. You would not only have to fulfill major requirements, but also college/dept requirements which this answer ignores.

Comment: @chevybow I think rather that this answer is simply not exhaustive to cover every institution's policies. If your institution has separate requirements beyond major requirements, that's their business; OP doesn't need to know that to understand what people are talking about when they refer to their majors or minors.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am not aware of public universities in the US giving you 2 degrees if you major in two completely different fields. Can you point me towards just one?

Comment: @chevybow Where do I say you get two degrees for majoring in different fields?

Comment: @chevybow I think you might be confused about what Bryan's answer and clarification are saying. What they're saying is that at most institutions in the US, if you double major in Bio and Chem, then you do receive a single Bachelors Degree, but that degree is officially in both Bio and Chem, not one or the other; it will have both fields listed on it, and it will satisfy either requirement for graduate programs or employment. And that's distinct from a double degree, by which I assume you mean two separate Bachelors degrees in Bio and Chem respectively.

Comment: @chevybow "If I double major in Bio and Chem, I can graduate with just a degree in Biology" I don't understand what you mean. Your college lets you opt out of being awarded the major? Why would you do that?

Answer (score 12):

It might be better to start by thinking what university study is like in the US. You go to the university, register as a student, and start working towards certain degrees. Those degrees will usually require you to take certain courses to graduate.

Here're the relevant webpages for physics at the University of Florida. This university has two kinds of bachelor's degree, [a BS degree and a BA degree, and also a physics minor](https://www.phys.ufl.edu/wp/index.php/undergraduate/degrees-offered/). Look at the three degrees and see the different requirements:

- The [BS degree](https://www.phys.ufl.edu/academics/undergraduate/reqBS.html) requires 41 physics credits, plus 7 chemistry credits and 21 mathematics credits, plus a few more courses required at university/college level.*
- The [BA degree](https://www.phys.ufl.edu/academics/undergraduate/reqBA.html) requires 32 physics credits, plus 7 chemistry credits and 18 mathematics credits, plus a few more courses required at university/college level.
- The physics minor requires only five physics courses.

Therefore we can say:

- The physics *major* will generally be working towards either the BS or BA degree. Because the BS degree requires more physics credits, people with a BS degree tend to know more physics than those with a BA degree (but those with a BA degree still know quite a bit about it). They also know a little chemistry and some math.
- The physics *minor* knows some physics, but relatively little of it. They've only taken five courses, compared to physics majors, who've taken at least twice the number.

You can see how this works for someone who's a physics major and a computer science minor - they took enough physics courses to know a lot about physics, and enough Computer Science courses to know something about CS (but not nearly as much as CS majors).

> I think I may have heard somewhere that because university is expensive in the US, you try to get more "value" out of your enrollment by taking multiple degrees (?).

Depends on how you view it. For example the university might expect you to take five courses a semester. Physics majors will generally take 3-4 of those in physics, and spend the remaining courses on the university or college requirements. If you major in physics and minor in CS, then you'll be focusing those remaining courses on CS. Comparatively, someone who's only majoring in physics will likely take a greater variety of courses (e.g. they could take a history course just to see what it's like).

It's also possible to overload. If the university requires you to take 5 courses a semester, you could take 6. It will take effort, but you'd learn more that semester, getting more "value" from your money.

Yet another possibility is to study longer. A hypothetical physics major could take CS courses and also the history course, plus economics, and archeology, and what have you. They might end up graduating in 5 years as opposed to their peers, but they'd still graduate with a physics degree.

Finally, it's possible to take enough courses to graduate with a double major (two major degrees), but it'll usually take longer because it's improbable to take all the required courses within the same time. (However, universities will usually have a limit to the maximum number of years you can study, and of course, it's not cheap.)

*The university might also have requirements - e.g. they might say "all science students need to take at least three courses outside their major, and at least one of those outside their faculty" (here "faculty" refers to the faculty of science, i.e., the university says you need to take a course that isn't a science course).

Comment: Meanwhile at UF, the Physics B.S. requires 21 credits in mathematics, while a Math minor requires 23-24. One required math class for Physics doesn't count for a math minor, so you need maybe 1 or 2 extra math classes.

Comment: Note that the map between "courses" and "credits" isn't obvious. One course could typically be anywhere from 3 to 5 credits. A credit maps more or less to the number of hours per week the course meets.

Comment: @mkennedy Well yes. The BA is also almost certainly set up to make it easier to double major in this respect. It's a common setup at UF.

Comment: Worth mentioning that while in that case (and in general) a BS requires more and more intensive of courses, there will be significant differences between schools. My college didn't give BSs, even in STEM majors, and my (single) major was 72 STEM credits of the ~130 I took during my time there

Answer (score 6):

The field of study one gets their bachelor's degree for is usually called the major. The minor is a package of a few courses in a different field of study that you take during your bachelor's.

[netherlands](/questions/tagged/netherlands)

For instance, in the Netherlands, most bachelor degrees require six semesters (180 ECTS) of study. This duration refers to the regular (or minimum) study time. Of these six, one semester (30 ECTS) or half a semester (15 ECTS) is allocated to the *minor program*. This is a group of courses arranged around a specific topic of study that doesn't need to relate to the major (e.g. major in Aerospace Engineering and minor in Forestry). However, some students do choose a minor on a narrow topic that deepens their knowledge in their major field of study (e.g. major in Aerospace Engineering and minor in Airport Development). You can do the minor at your home university or a different university. Most universities in Belgium and the Netherlands offer several packaged minor programs on specific topics that you can choose from (e.g. Translating English to Dutch, Artificial Intelligence and Societal Impacts, [and many more](https://eduxchange.nl/for-students-eur/explore)). Alternatively, you can pick some courses that arguably cover a coherent topic and get it approved as your individual minor program. The latter option opens the door to doing the minor semester further abroad, which is popular.
The main study program completed in the remaining (e.g. 5) semesters is called the *major*.

Comment: What's a semester in this context? Granted that we're both Europeans of sorts, but the term is virtually unknown in the UK.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd a semester is half an academic year just like everywhere else. It's only an informal term. Many Dutch universities formally divide the academic year into shorter periods. We had five: two in the fall semester, two in the spring semester and one in the summer "break".

Comment: Right, half a year thanks. As I said, it's not used in the UK so your "everywhere else" is spurious.

Comment: Semesters do exist at some UK universities ─ [BCU](https://www.bcu.ac.uk/student-info/welcome/when-you-get-here/timetables) has them, apparently [Manchester](https://www.manchester.ac.uk/discover/key-dates/), [Sheffield](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/about/dates/current-and-future-semester) and [St. Andrews](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/semester-dates/) do too. There are probably more.

Comment: I work at a UK university, and we always talk about our academic year as organised in semester A, semester B and semester C (where C is the summer semester, where not much happens)

Comment: @penelope So in at least your case they correspond to traditional third-of-a-year terms.